# Can't connect to a win2003 pptp vpn if the cisco vpn service is running

Tags: windows-xp, windows-server-2003, cisco-vpn-client, pptp

I have a PPTP VPN set-up on a windows 2003 domain controller. Every attempt to connect to the VPN from a client running XP sp3 fails with a 619 error. Googling around I've found a [2006 thread on Google Answers](http://answers.google.com/answers/threadview/id/710777.html) that points to issues with the Cisco VPN client, that sure enough is installed on the client box. Stopping the "Cisco VPN service" from the MMC console fixes the problem (quitting the vpn-client isn't enough it seems).

Has anyone else experienced this? Any idea what's wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

From [Cisco VPN Client breaks Microsoft PPTP VPN connections](http://software.itags.org/cisco/69710/)

> This may work, go into the settings
>   for your PPTP connection, and go to
>   the network tab, untick "Determanistic
>   Network Enhancer".
>
> This worked with me to get an Intel
>   VPN client working.